# Safely give secret/token to Kafka Connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, secret-key

We are using Kafka Connectors (JDBC and others), and configuring them using the REST API (using `curl` in shell scripts). Right now, when testing/developing, we are including secrets (for the JDBC connect - database user/pw) directly in the request. This is obviously bad, as those are then readily available for everybody to see when reading them out using the GET request.

Is there a good way to give secrets to the connectors? We can bring them in safely using environment variables or config files (injected fom OpenShift) - but is there a syntax available when starting a connector via the REST API for that?

EDIT: This is for the distributed mode of connectors; i.e., configuration by REST API, not connector config files...

Comment: How are you planning on using environment variables within the connect configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pluggable interface for this was implemented in Apache Kafka 2.0 through [KIP-297](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations). You can see more details in the [documented example here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html#externalizing-secrets).

Comment: There's still an open JIRA that exposes the password later at /config endpoint, I saw

Comment: Thanks so far. That pages shows the way with config files (i.e., a config file which contains the secret; possible injected by openshift in my case) which would be cool. I have not found out yet whether this can be used in a connector configured/created via REST API, but will try to figure it out later... or did you do that already, @RobinMoffatt?

Comment: @AnoE The REST API is the only way to make connectors, so yes. The file needs to already exist in your containers/hosts.